# Default Sublime Text 3 to use spaces instead of tabs

Tags: sublime-text-3

Indentantion is done by default using tabs for any new document, how can I change it to use spaces instead?

Mark this by default

|

V

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and add the following line:

```js
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```